# String regular expressions for URL Rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

**Rule :**

```
<rule name="rule1">
<match url="^variation1 or variation2/([^_]+)" ignoreCase="true"/>
<action type="Rewrite" url="strings.aspx?x1={R:1}&amp;x2={R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

I want to variation1 or variation2 match this rule.

**Example URL:**

- .http://localhost/variation1/3242ddfw
- .http://localhost/variation2/3242ddfw

Note : Not two rule using. Only one rule

Thank you for help me

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :)

```
<rule name="rule1">
    <match url="^(variation1|variation2)/([^_]+)" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="strings.aspx?x1={R:2}&amp;x2={R:3}"/>
</rule>
```

Note : parameter count increased. R:1 -> R:2, R:2 -> R:3